# SSO - Active Directory to Hosted Linux

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a CodeIgniter based application running on a hosted Linux Apache web server.  Subscribers to the site log in via the normal username / password combination.

One of the client companies who subscribe to the site has asked if their users can be authenticated via SSO.   The client company users will be on Microsoft Domains.

I know this is a big subject and is going to take a lot of understanding, but is this possible?

If I could be pointed in the right direction, I can do the research.